# Использование fork() с plainTextEdit

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Хочу просто добавить любой текст в plainTextEdit в процессе родителе и в дочернем процессе, т. к. plainTextEdit это общий ресурс, нужно синхронизировать взаимодействие процессов через семафор, вроде все должно работать, но не тут то было. При нажатии на кнопку записывается паралельно и одновременно два текста. Почему-то семафор не может справиться с этим. Пробовал через мютекс и там тоже самое было. В общем вот код:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSystemSemaphore sem("market", 1, QSystemSemaphore::Create);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            char resultString[100];
            sprintf(resultString, "Дочерний процесс: %d\n", getpid());

            QString text = resultString;

            sem.acquire();

            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(text);

            sem.release();

            break;
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            char resultString[100];
            sprintf(resultString, "Родительский процесс: %d\n", getpid());

            QString text = resultString;

            sem.acquire();

            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(text);

            sem.release();

            break;
        } else {
            QString errorText = "Ошибка при вызове fork()\n";
            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(errorText);
        }
    }
} 

Библиотеки: 
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QSemaphore>
#include<QSystemSemaphore>  

Много лишних библиотек есть я знаю
```

Comment: В вашем примере нет общих ресурсов. Копайте в сторону IPC.

Comment: команда `fork` создаёт копию процесса. И у этих процессов тем общей памяти. Семафоры и мютексы разработаны для нитей. Вам нужно создать новую нить, а не процесс.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Вообще-то семафоры и мютексы вполне себе могут работать и между процессами. QSystemSemaphore предназначен именно для этого.

Comment: `Unlike QSemaphore, a QSystemSemaphore can also be accessed from multiple processes.` - это переводится как? @user7860670

Comment: @AlexGlebe В отличии от `QSemaphore`, к `QSystemSemaphore` может также быть использован из нескольких процессов. ¿Что вас не устраивает?

Comment: плохая идея в кучу сваливать Qt и fork. Чем вам QThread не угодил если уж нужны потоки?